# sending data from one app to another app in android(AIR for ANDROID)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

As we can send data from one Activity to another within the app and also from one app to another app by using `Intent`
I'm able to send data from my one app to another by using following code
just consider there are two apps `APP1` and `APP2` and I'm sending data from `APP1` to `APP2` and vice verse.

In `APP1` package name: `(com.sush.myApp)`

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // to receive data from com.my.demo package and display it to TextView
        TextView mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String name=getIntent().getStringExtra("User_Message");
        mText.setText(name);

        // to send data from com.sush.myApp package to com.my.demo package
        Button btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
              {

                try
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
                    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.my.demo");
                    i.putExtra("User_ID", "sush19");
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    startActivity(i);
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "App Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

              }
        });
    }
```

and from `APP2` package name: `(com.my.demo)`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // to receive data from com.sush.myApp package and display it to TextView
        final TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text1);
        String name=getIntent().getStringExtra("User_ID");
        txt1.setText(name);

        // to send data from com.my.demo package to com.sush.myApp package
        Button btnSending = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        final EditText myMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        btnSending.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (myMessage.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Enter your message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {

                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
                        i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sush.myApp");
                        i.putExtra("User_Message", myMessage.getText().toString());
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Error: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And its working perfect..
`Now my problem is I want to do same operation i.e sending data from one app to another but my first app is in Java created using Eclipse and my second app is in ActionScript created using AIR for Android in Adobe Flash Professional CS6`

Is there a way to use `Intent` and `PackageManager` in `Actionscript` so that I can send the data easily from AIR app to Android App, if yes then can anyone show me  a example
Or else can anyone show me an example on how to send data from Android App to AIR for Android App and vice verse..
Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 methods I can think of for this.

The first is to use the Java code you have written (or similar), package it as a [Native Extension](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html), and build that into your app.

Another alternative is to use a URI scheme and read the data from the InvokeEvent. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591086/passing-parameters-from-a-java-activity-to-adobe-air-app) covers that method already.